# How should I sum doubles in Idris?

Tags: idris, idris2

I don't understand why the following does not work:

```
Main> 2.1 + 2.3
Error: Can't find an implementation for FromDouble Integer.

(Interactive):1:1--1:4
 1 | 2.1 + 2.3
     ^^^
```

It works with integers, and [if I understand the docs correctly, it **should** work with doubles too](https://www.idris-lang.org/docs/idris2/current/prelude_docs/docs/Prelude.Num.html)!

I get the same error with `2.1 * 2.3`, but `2.1 - 2.3` and `abs 2.1` work fine, which gives me the impression that there is a problem with the `Num` interface. However I'm a total beginner in Idris, so maybe I'm missing something very silly! I could not find any example of summing doubles on the web…

(I compiled Idris2 from the latest commit on github — `69f680e10a336c4f33414cfd55c13d41b68d735b`.)

---

Edited to add: `2.1 + 2.3` actually works in a file (defining a constant), the problem only occurs in the REPL. I guess I'll have to file a bug.

Comment: I imagine `the Double (2.1 + 2.3)` also works in the REPL?

Comment: Indeed it does!